# How can I receive mail using .NET?

Tags: c#, smtp, open-source, pop3

I need an Open Source C# program that can receive SMTP messages and save them in a class (and sends mail, but this is optional since I found a lot of those)

Does this program use SMTP or POP3 to receive mail?

Comment: An SMTP server is what will receive incoming mail.  A POP3 server is what allows an email client to read a user's mailbox.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're after, but what I used to grab/view mail is Papercut, [found here on codeplex](http://papercut.codeplex.com/).

You can see how it listens for mail, etc in the source.  It's handy for just sitting in your tray and viewing messages as they come in without needing a SMTP server setup at all.  It acts as the SMTP server, just point the app sending mail the machine running it.

Comment: Thanks, but I need an open source SMTP server
this is not open source

Comment: @John - Sure it is, most things on CodePlex are: http://papercut.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=papercut&changeSetId=44151 License can be found here: http://papercut.codeplex.com/license

Comment: I thought the 'Apache' license was pretty permissive? If not enough, please add license conditions to your question.

Comment: @John, Apache license matches OSI open source definition. :) Regards,